# Phabricator SSL certificate not trusted

Tags: php, curl, ssl, phabricator, arcanist

I have problem with **arc install-certificate** instruction

Configuration : Linux Mint 16 (Petra)

What I did by now :

1. I have put my public key to phabricator web (I can now do all git instructions with no problem)
2. I have downloaded my custom.pem certificate and put it into libphutil/resources/ssl directory.
3. I have followed instructions in README file (it is in the same dir) and modified this line in **php.ini** file :

   curl.cainfo = /home/ilongin/job/tools/arcanist/libphutil/resources/ssl/custom.pem

But still when I run **arc install-certificate** inside my project dir I get :

Trying to connect to server...
Usage Exception: Failed to connect to server: [cURL/60] (OUR-PHAB-SERVER-URL)  There was an error verifying the SSL Certificate Authority while negotiating the SSL connection. This usually indicates that you are using a self-signed certificate but have not added your CA to the CA bundle. See instructions in "libphutil/resources/ssl/README".

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like there is some strange bug related with SSL + curl + phabricator stack and this is where you can find some additional info https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/troubleshooting_https/ ... my solution was to put blindly trust domain like mentioned in article (not so perfect solution but at least it works) .. hope this help someone someday :)